# Is it possible to template basic_string<>::iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Im using g++4.6 and I tried to template my class based on the char type used, but my variables arent only chars but also strings of those chars. So I tried something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
//... 
//constructor
Node(std::basic_string<T> str, std::basic_string<T>::iterator it)
{
}
//usage 
Node<char16_t> start;
```

but I get 
‘std::basic_string<_CharT, std::char_traits<_CharT>, std::allocator<_Tp1> >::iterator’ is not a type
When I replace second T  in the constructor arg list to be char16_t it compiles.

Comment: Make that `typename std::basic_string<T>::iterator it`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why isn't your constructor also called `FSDNode`?

`std::basic_string<T>::iterator` is a dependent type, since it depends on template paramter `T`. So you need to add `typename` to the argument type.

```
FSDNode(std::basic_string<T> str, typename std::basic_string<T>::iterator it)
{
}
```

Comment: Was just generalizing code during pasting... ill fix the typo